# POST "/v1/rest-apis" not working as expected

Tags: marklogic

In the cluster there are two groups e-node and d-node both containing host e-host and d-host respectively.

On doing POST call to `e-host:8002/v1/rest-apis` getting the error, however the same is working for `d-host:8002/v1/rest-apis`.

```
Error: "/common-api/endpoints/rest-apis/rest-api-list.xqy?version=v1 was not found"
```

Not able to understand the reason behind this error although '8002' management port is available on both hosts.

Comment: Do you have App-Services (8000) in that group as well?  You may need to add it.

Comment: App-Services (8000) is present in both groups.

Comment: Are the Manage servers (8002) configured identically in the two groups?

Comment: And where they created automatically by MarkLogic, or added manually?